# Problem with RUN command in Dockerfile on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: python, filesystem, docker, volume-control, container

I am new with docker.
I have the following Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/media && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/static && \
    chown -R django-user:django-user /vol && \
    chmod -R 755 /vol && \
    
ENV PATH="/py/bin:$PATH"

USER django-user
```

and this docker-compose file

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - DEV=true
    container_name: app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - data:/vol/web
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
  
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
  ......

volumes:
  data:
```

I am a bit confused on how RUN instruction work.

1. After running `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` commands, I have my container build. But my problem is, I accessed my app container by running `$ docker exec -it app sh` command, but inside I don't see `/vol/web/media` and `/vol/web/static` which for me are supposed to be created during the build of Dockerfile.
   Why I cannot find these two folders in my app container? where they are?
2. When running RUN instructions in a Dockerfile to install for example some packages, where do that packages are installed? In my Ubuntu host machine or in the file system of container?

Comment: hi @Jules Betfien, 1) you mount the local directory `data` in your container to `/vol/web` this mount hides the directories `/vol/web/media` and `/vol/web/static` if you need these dierectories add them to the local data directory. 2) packages are installed in the container.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to access /vol/web/ directory. When /vol/web/ directory is created by RUN instruction of dockerfile where is it situated? In the container?

Comment: if you create a directory within the dockerfile with RUN it is inside the container. you can see these directories if you remove the line  `- data:/vol/web` from you docker compose file.